# how to remove open-jdk completely in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, java

I hava installed oracle-jdk,so want to remove openjdk completely to ensure every java-based apps will use oracle jdk,but when I try to run "sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-*",ubuntu will remove openjdk-6 but try to install openjdk-7-* at the same time automatically.
   So,how to remove openjdk-6 and stop ubuntu to install openjdk-7 at the same time.

Comment: Please consider moving this question to http://askubuntu.com

Comment: this is a perfect solution,http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43150/how-to-completely-remove-java-6-and-install-java-jdk-7-on-linux-mint-13

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally,I got a solution:disconnect from Internet,then do removing,it is removed completely

Comment: use `sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\* icedtea-\* icedtea6-\*`, be careful.

Comment: @S.D. Or using `apt-get purge openjdk*`

Answer (score 13):

`update-alternatives` does a great job switching the default java version, just in case you haven't known it:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1071      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java              1065      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1071      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Comment: I download java 7 from sun's website,and installed it manaully.So when  running this command,get:
    update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java.

Comment: @AlexLuya I usually do this through custom ppa's. But you can configure your `update-alternatives`, though it's may be not a pleasant work.

Comment: @EarlGray: Thank you so much, this is brilliant! Also, try this for the installation stages: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this while turn off your internet.

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jdk icedtea icedtea6
```

You may want to check out galternatives to switch program before uninstall.

```
sudo apt-get install galternatives
```

Comment: How do I purge OpenJDK 11?

Comment: sudo apt-get purge openjdk-version-jre openjdk-version-jdk